# This post is marked as a duplicate, but none of the "original" questions provide the actual answer

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have run into an issue and Googled and found [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/451353/54495) to my issue. In Ventura, I'm finding that Finder windows will follow me from space to space. It's marked as a duplicate and 4 other questions are linked to as the original. But not one of those answers applies to this situation.

In all the linked questions, the one answer (always by the same user) is to select "None." This may work for a single program, like Notes, Mail, VLC, or Preview, which are the programs asked about in the other four questions, but it doesn't work for Finder, where, many times, we may be using multiple Finder windows. In the question, the user specifies it is *Finder* windows that are having this problem, not single programs. He also provides details that indicate he *may* have tried the answer in the other 4 questions. (Although I admit, it's not clear, but that should have been asked about in the comments before closing the question.)

I don't want to ask a similar question just to have it closed, but I do have additional details to include and I feel the community is not being well served by closing this. In my case I have multiple Finder windows open at a time. For instance, in WS1 (Workspace 1), I keep a window open to where my STL files for 3D printing are stored so I can just drag and drop STL files into my slicer. In WS9, I have a Finder window open with 2 tabs in it for programs I run in that workspace. I have 3 other workspaces where I have Finder windows that I use for the work I do in that workspace. These windows keep sliding from one space to another, stopping somewhere along the way, so these finder windows are not acting as if they are assigned to "All Desktops." Also, when a window slides along with me (the question mentions using Mission Control - I usually swipe, or use a macro that does multiple swipes - but this happens without that macro), if multiple tabs are open, it always jumps back to the first tab.

I'll grant that I'm adding some information, but I think even with the information in the question specifying Finder, it's clear it's not the "All Desktop" issue. For instance, I was in WS9, swiped (a 3 finger swipe left or right moves to the workspace on the appropriate side) to WS8, then 7, 6, and to 5. The Finder window in WS9 will follow to WS8, and SOMETIMES to WS5. But it is NOT in every workspace or desktop. So it's not acting as if All Desktops is selected. The window MOVES.

I'd like to ask this as a new question and provide the additional information, since I'm finding that this issue is not unique to me - other people are having this issue, but I also don't want to ask and have the question closed by people who may not be reading all the information in the question and realizing it's not a duplicate.

My first thought is the original question I linked to should be reopened, but, after thinking about it, I just want to make sure if I ask a new question and provide all this extra information, it's not going to be closed down as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

As other users already explained in the comments beneath the question, your problem seems to be different from the one in the (closed) question. So please ask a new one.

Comment: My concern is that the closed question is rather different from the dupes, but still marked as a dupe. I don't want it to get relegated to that same treatment.

Comment: The best thing about asking a specific concrete question is that it's easy to SHOW in words how questions are different, and there are edits to help and even closes can be re-opened / reversed / revised over time as clarity and consensus arrive @Tango Having 5 or 6 duplicates isn't a problem here - in fact it's a feature since all the wordings help people search for, find and then get to the answers provided.

Comment: @bmike Thank you. I'll probably post it tonight, since I'm tied up for a few hours. Honestly, due to what I'm seeing, I'm pretty sure it's a bug, since it's inconsistent - only some windows do this. Also, thanks for the point about dupes. There are some sections of SE that can be rather tough about such issues - it's frustrating to explain why a question isn't a dupe, have it closed as one, and have to push to get it reopened. Doesn't happen often, but it does.

Comment: You are correct @Tango these things often take us a week or more to unravel as moderators. No rush on the post - do it when the time is right and feel free to @ us in chat or link to it in the body of the post above if you want extra eyes on it.

Comment: @bmike I may not be posting it. I can't duplicate the behavior right now and the spotty behavior makes me think it's a bug, not a feature. Also, thanks for the comments. There are sections I won't even go to in SE anymore because the community is so aggressive in sticking to the rules that they have little interest in actually helping people get answers.